# Map ordinal to alphabet in shell script

Tags: shell-script

Is there any simple solution to map ordinal number like 1, 2, 3, ... to alphabet a, b, c in a shell script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Bourne-like shells:

```
$ set a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
$ echo "$5"
e
```

(with recent versions of `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`, you can shorten the `set` line to `set {a..z}`)

Or:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%c\n", 0x60 + 5)}'
e
```

With some implementations of `dc` (at least GNU `dc`):

```
$ echo 96 5 + P | dc
e
```

With `zsh`, you can use base 36:

```
$ echo $(([##36] 9 + 5))
E
```

Or use `\0ooo` octal sequences in `printf %b`:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "\0$(([##8]0x60 + 5))"
e
```

For non-English alphabets, assuming a UTF-8 locale (here for Greek):

```
$ printf '%b\n' "\u$(([##16]0x3B0 + 5))"
ε
```

That's based on the character sequence in Unicode, there's not much guarantee that that order will match the common alphabetical order for your language in your region, so you may as well hard code the full list of characters by hand and use the first form.

Like for the russian alphabet (according to Wikipedia):

```
$ set а б в г д е ё ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я
$ echo "$5"
д
```

Which doesn't match the Unicode order exactly.

Comment: for shells with arrays and {a..z} expansion, if you want to avoid clobbering the positional parameters $1, $2, etc, but don't mind creating a new variable, `a=({a..z}); echo ${a[5]}`

Comment: up for base 36 solution. Associative array, something like array[$i]=letteri, comes to my mind first.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, that works for `zsh` but for `ksh93` or `bash`, you need `a=('' {a..z})` (or `a=([1]=a {b..z})` with `bash` only) as [those shells start their arrays on index 0 and not 1 contrary to all other shells](/a/252405).